# como puedo pedir al usuario que ingrese dos nombres y dos apellidos, solo letras

Tags: python, validación

```
validacion=''
lista=[]
while validacion!=validacion:
    nombres = input('Ingrese nombres completos:')
    lista=nombres.split(" ")
    validacion=len(lista)
    if validacion==4 and nombres.isalpha():
        print(nombres)
    print('¡Solo ingrese letras!')
```

Comment: ¿Qué se supone que significa el código que adjuntas? ¿Es tu intento de resolverlo? ¿No te funciona? ¿Por qué? A primera vista lo veo casi correcto (aunque no entiendo bien la especificación del problema), excepto por la condición del `while`, que obviamente va a ser siempre falsa, ya que una variable no puede ser distinta a sí misma. Yo cambiaría la condición por `while True` (bucle infinito) y saldría de él con un `break` cuando se detecta bien el nombre (tras `print(nombres)`).

Comment: Deberías de añadir más información de lo que representa tu código

Answer (score 1):

Recomiendo utilices expresiones regulares, ya que existen apellidos que son conformados por 2 palabras ej. **"de León"**, entonces si el usuario se llama *Fulanito Campirano Melendez de Leon*, obtendrás 5 elementos en tu lista.

```
import re
# Especificamos que validaremos Letras Mayusculas, Minúsculas y espacio en blanco
# Esperamos como mínimo 2 caracteres y un máximo de 20
palabra = re.compile(r'^[A-Z|a-z| ]{2,20}$')

# Preparamos las solicitudes por Orden
preguntas = ("1er Nombre: ", "2do Nombre: ", "1er Apellido: ", "2do Apellido: ")
respuestas = []

for i in preguntas:
    rsp = input(i)
    if palabra.search(rsp):
        respuestas.append(rsp)
    else:
        # En caso de no cumplir la expresión regular (en 2do nombre solo dio enter)
        respuestas.append(" ")

print(respuestas)
```

**NOTA:** En este ejemplo no incluyo la validación de la letra Ñ y letras acentuadas.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta con esto

```
validacion=''
lista=[]
while True:
    nombre = input("Dime tu nombre completo")
    validacion = {"0" for i in lista if not i.isalpha() and not i==" "}
    if len(validacion)>0:
        print("Solo letras")
   else:
        if len(nombre.split(" "))>2:
            datos = nombre.split(" ", 3)
            nombre1= datos[0]
            nombre2= datos[1]
            apellido1 = datos[2]
            if len(nombre.split(" "))>3:
                apellido2 = datos[3]
            else:
                apellido2 = ""
            break

        else:
            print("Faltan datos")
lista.append("Nombre: "+nombre1+" Segundo nombre: " + nombre2 + " Apellido: "+ apellido1+" Segundo apellido: "+apellido2)
```

Answer (score 1):

En este caso la solución se puede hacer con regex y meta caracteres de forma simple;para usarse solo tienes que incluir `import re` en tu codigo

```
import re
```

Te comparto un código que valida que no se usen caracteres complejos o numeros es decir solo letras ya sean mayúsculas o minúsculas:

```
import re

while(True):

    x = str(input("Introduce tu nombre completo: "))

    if(re.search("^[a-zA-Z|ñÑ ]+$",x)is not None):
        print("validacion completa")
        break
    else:
        print("No es posible continuar(caracteres invalidos)")
```

Te comparto:

[Documentacion oficial de python regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)

[Herramienta oficial para regex online](https://regex101.com/)

**NOTA:** Las personas suelen tener entre 1-3 nombres y en casos extraños pueden tener mas ;en cuanto a apellidos estos pueden tener uno(caso de ser extranjeros como en usa) o dos pero que pueden estar formulados por n palabras.Sugerencia : no contar n cantidad de nombres o apellidos .

Answer (score -2):

Puedes usar esta funcion a ver si te funciona

```
function soloLetras($in): 
 if(preg_match('/[^a-Z]/',$in)):
   return false
 else: 
   return true
```